# Cannot find symbol error. java

Tags: java, actionlistener, mouselistener

I am running the following code and i am getting a cannot find symbol error at        resultPane.setResult(0); am i putting the new handlerclass in wrong spot? ive tried putting 
it in different spots but nothing

```
public class MovingLabel {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MovingLabel();
}
public MovingLabel() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            ResultPane resultPane = new ResultPane();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setGlassPane(resultPane);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new NewPane(resultPane));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setBounds(500,300,200,200);
        }
    });
}
public class ResultPane extends JPanel {
     private JLabel result;
    private Timer timer;

    private int xDelta = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : -1;
    private int yDelta = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : -1;



    public ResultPane() {
        setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(null);
        result = new JLabel();
        Font font = result.getFont();
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 26f);
        result.setFont(font);
        add(result);
        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        result.addMouseListener(handler);
        result.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Point point = result.getLocation();
                point.x += xDelta;
                point.y += yDelta;
                if (point.x < 0) {
                    point.x = 0;
                    xDelta *= -1;
                } else if (point.x + result.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                    point.x = getWidth() - result.getWidth();
                    xDelta *= -1;
                }
                if (point.y < 0) {
                    point.y = 0;
                    yDelta *= -1;
                } else if (point.y + result.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
                    point.y = getHeight() - result.getHeight();
                    yDelta *= -1;
                }
                result.setLocation(point);
                repaint();
            }

        });
        timer.start();

    }


    public void setResult(Number number) {
        result.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(number));
        result.setSize(result.getPreferredSize());
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
public class NewPane extends JPanel {
    private final ResultPane resultPane;

    public NewPane(ResultPane resultPane) {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        this.resultPane = resultPane;

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.add(new JButton(new LabelAction()));

        add(buttons, gbc);

    }
    public class LabelAction extends AbstractAction {
        LabelAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "Label");
        }

        @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            resultPane.setResult(123);
         }
    }

}
private class HandlerClass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            resultPane.setResult(0);
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: there is no resultPane in HandlerClass

Comment: Yeah, move the whole `HandlerClass` up one line, so that it's inside `NewPane`, if you want it to have access to `resultPane`.

Comment: +1 for a nice program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `resultPane` instance variable. You can't access local variable outside the method.

```
  class MovingLabel {

        private ResultPane resultPane; // Declare it as instance variable

        public MovingLabel() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ...
                    resultPane = new ResultPane(); // Initialize the instance variable
                    ...
                }
         } 
  }
```

It's a nice program.

[image]

Comment: you've fixed my problem but during runtime im getting lots of errors in my general output. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: OK then I have to run it. Look at the line no where you are getting Exception.

Comment: Its working. you haven't initialized it inside the run() method. Look at my post again.

Comment: Doesnt tell me which line

Comment: `ResultPane resultPane = new ResultPane();` should be converted to `resultPane = new ResultPane();` inside `run()` method to initialize the instance variable that we have declared in the class.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to remove ResultPane resultPane = new ResultPane();

Comment: Don't remove it. just replace it as I suggested in my post as inline comments.

Comment: One more solution : You can do it in the same way as you are doing for `NewPane` class. Passing `ResultPane` object to the `HandlerClass` class in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`resultPane` is only defined in the scope of `run()`. If you want `HandlerClass` to have access to it you need to give it a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I put every class in a new file. For me it easier to understand scope.  The problem is indeed that the reference in `HandlerClass` is outside of it's declaration in the other classes.